# Solr issues with encoding UTF-8 with JAVA

Tags: java, utf-8, solr

I have an issue with Solr and Java. I made a program that post tweets to Solr but when the text has accent characters or emojis Solr store them as \uFFFD. For example: 
`Hoy es el d�a de un gran amigo que purifica`.

I thought that it was a problem with the code, so it was forced to store the data in UTF-8

```
    String data = "{\"add\":{ \"doc\":" + json + "}}";
    String value = new String(data.getBytes("UTF-8"),"UTF-8");
    StringEntity input = new StringEntity(value);
    input.setContentType("application/json");
    input.setContentEncoding("UTF-8");
```

And posting the data locally to amazon (solr is there) works, but if I run the code from Amazon the encoding problems persist.

Oddly, besides Solr, the data is stored on PostgreSql and doesn't have any problem.

What could be the problem?
What kind of configuration could I be missing on amazon?

Any ideas are welcome!

Comment: what do you expect `String value = new String(data.getBytes("UTF-8"),"UTF-8");` to do? That's not helping you. It's not at all clear where the problem comes in - for example, whether the `json` is correct, or where you're seeing the problem.